# fetching data. for user from firebase for flutter gives null

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

After i have created the sign in and signup in flutter and i have connect it to firebase, i added a textfield for the name of the user. So if the user register his name also will be stored, then this data is saved into firebase with the id of the user. The problem is when i try to fetch this data my these method it gives me null ,

This is the way how i am fetching the data of the user :

```
class WelcomePage  extends StatefulWidget {
  String email;
   WelcomePage ({Key? key, required this.email}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<WelcomePage> createState() => _WelcomePageState();
}

class _WelcomePageState extends State<WelcomePage> {
  ScrollController? _scrollcontroller;
  final FirebaseAuth _auth =FirebaseAuth.instance;
  String? _name ;
  String? _uid;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollcontroller = ScrollController();
    _scrollcontroller?.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
    getData();
  }

  void getData() async{
    User? user = _auth.currentUser;
    _uid = user!.uid;
    final DocumentSnapshot userDoc  =
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user.uid).get();

    _name = userDoc.get('name');
  }
```

Comment: It sounds like no document exists for `user.uid` in that case. If you check in the Firestore console, do you see a document for that user? If not, this code is working as expected and the problem is more likely in where you *write* the user data.

Comment: actully  i have created a collection for users and when the user create account his name is created in the collection as field for example name : BoB

Comment: Your code doesn't look for a user by their name BoB though, it looks for a document for their UID.